# Removing durability one unit at a time

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was wondering if it is possible to have a command that would remove one durability from an item each time it ran. The best way I can come up with is a having a huge array of command blocks with:
`/replaceitem entity @a slot.hotbar.0 minecraft:shield 1 350`,
then `/replaceitem entity @a slot.hotbar.0 minecraft:shield 1 349` ect .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to subtract durability from an item the player is holding in their hand?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354341/how-to-subtract-durability-from-an-item-the-player-is-holding-in-their-hand)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution would be the best solution. You can probably write an MCEdit filter to easily place all of those command blocks.

Another solution would be summoning a zombie at the player's location `execute <player> ~ ~ ~ summon Zombie`. The zombie will hit the player and the shield (or armour, won't work with tools) will take damage. It'll be a good idea to give the player resistance as well using `effect <player> resistance <seconds> 255 true` (the "true" at the end of the command hides particles).