# How to subtract durability from an item the player is holding in their hand?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm in Java in 1.14.3 and I'm trying to create a custom mining tool using the stone hoe.  Whenever the player mines with it, I want it to take durability/damage.  I created a scoreboard `scoreboard objectives add usedTool minecraft.mined:minecraft.stripped_spruce_log.`  Now, whenever the player mines, I check if they have the stone hoe in their hand: `execute as @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:stone_hoe"}}] if entity @s[scores={usedTool=..1}] run [...]` Is there a way I can subtract durability from the stone hoe after the player has mined with it?

Comment: Are you in the latest version (1.14.3) on Java edition?

Comment: @Nik3141Yes sorry, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: No problem I just like to title minecraft questions a particular way to make them easier to understand at first glance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `execute store result entity @s SelectedItem.tag.Damage int 1 run <some command that returns a value>`. This will set the `Damage` of the tool (how much it has been used) to the value of whatever command you put after the run. The 1 after the `int` is a scale factor of 1.

You can make a system where after the item is used, you store the durability somewhere with `execute store result score <entity> <objective> run data get entity @s SelectedItem.tag.Damage 1`,then use `scoreboard players add <entity> <objective> 1` to *add* one to the value (because you are adding damage, effectively removing durability), and then use the above `execute store result entity @s SelectedItem.tag.Damage int 1 run scoreboard players get <entity> <objective>` to store that modified value back into the `Damage` tag.

Comment: What a hidden gem. Didn't know you could store player nbt data with this command! Don't tell mojang please, this is something they don't need to change.